# Create entities with custom mime type as addition to spring data rest controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have `@Entity` called `Scenario`. I have a `@Repository` for it and spring data rest which generates MVC controller for the CRUD operations. The path is `/api/scenarios`. Works.

I want to be able to `POST` to the `/api/scenarios` endpoint not only with the default JSON but also with `multipart/form-data` so I can create my `Scenario` from a file which the user uploads. I tried creating custom `@Controller`:

```
@RestController
public class ImportController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/scenarios", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadScenario(@RequestPart(name = "scenario") MultipartFile scenarioFile) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With this the upload for `multipart/form-data` works but I can no longer access the enpoint with `GET`. I'm getting *Method not allowed*. Like if my custom controller hides the one generated by spring data rest.

Is there a way how to add such custom `POST` on top of the existing controller so I can create my `Scenario`s with both JSON and application/form-data mime types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify this custom controller as **repository controller** than Spring will add your custom methods to that generated controller.

**Please note, you don't need to add api base path to your controller mapping.** So, your mapping here is `"/scenarios"`, not `"/api/scenarios"`

```
    @RepositoryRestController
    @RequestMapping("/scenarios")
    public class ImportController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadScenario(@RequestPart(name = "scenario") MultipartFile scenarioFile) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, the `/scenarios` vs `/api/scenarios` was the part I missed. I tried `@RepositoryRestController` but had no luck due to the wrong path. Thank!